Maui Shell weird navigation issue with timing of ApplyQueryAttributes and Page Lifecycle
Having a bit of a weird one with Shell navigation and the timing of ApplyQueryAttributes relative to other page lifecycle events.
My app navigates to a MainPage with a menu that then navigates through other pages in the app until it reaches a page that requires a Flyout Menu (at which point I set the Shell.Current.FlyoutContent).
So
MainPage > PageA > PageB > PageWithFlyoutMenu
I'm performing the navigation as follows
MainPage to PageA: await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"PageA", true);
Lifecycle event order:
Constructor > ApplyQueryAttributes > OnAppearing > OnNavigatedTo
PageA to PageB: await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"PageB");
Lifecycle event order:
Constructor > ApplyQueryAttributes > OnAppearing > OnNavigatedTo
PageB to PageWithFlyoutMenu:
Shell.Current.FlyoutContent = IPlatformApplication.Current?.Services.GetService<MenuPage>(); await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///PageWithFlyoutMenu-1");
Lifecycle event order:
Constructor > OnAppearing > OnNavigatedTo > ApplyQueryAttributes
The issue here is that ApplyQueryAttributes is the last to be invoked.
AppShell is as follows:
<Shell
x:Class="****.AppShell"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:****.Views"
xmlns:localDetail="clr-namespace:****.Views.DetailPages"
Title="****">

<ShellContent
    Title="MainPage"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
    FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
    Route="MainPage"
    Shell.FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" />

<ShellContent
    Title="PageWithFlyoutMenu-1"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate localDetail:PageWithFlyoutMenu-1}"
    Route="PageWithFlyoutMenu-1" />

<ShellContent
    Title="PageWithFlyoutMenu-2"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate localDetail:PageWithFlyoutMenu-2}"
    Route="PageWithFlyoutMenu-2" />

</Shell>

And I have the following routes registered:
Routing.RegisterRoute("PageA", typeof(PageA));
Routing.RegisterRoute("PageB", typeof(PageB));

EDIT: ApplyQueryAttributes in PageB as requested in comments:
public override void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
{
    Tracker.WriteLine();

    if (query.ContainsKey("MyDto"))
    {
        var myParameter = query["MyDto"] as MyDto;

        if (myParameter != null) MyId = new Guid(myParameter.MyId);
    }
    
    base.ApplyQueryAttributes(query);
}

Can anyone shed any light on why this would be?
Link to Repo

What type of Page is PageWithFlyoutMenu-1? Is it ContentPage or FlyoutPage? Besides, please add the code about ApplyQueryAttributes and OnAppearing in the PageB.cs file

HI, Thanks for reply. PageWithFlyoutMenu-1 is a ContentPage. I'm also setting the FlyoutContent prior to navigation from PageB to PageWithFlyoutMenu as follows: Shell.Current.FlyoutContent = IPlatformApplication.Current?.Services.GetService();

I've updated the question to respond to your requests. Thanks.

@ShuowenHe-MSFT Hi, I've created a Sample repo and added a link to the post

So, in anticipation, when jumping from PageB  to PageWithFlyoutMenu, Lifecycle event order should be like the previous order Constructor > ApplyQueryAttributes > OnAppearing > OnNavigatedTo, right

Yes, that's how it works on PageA and PageB. Which makes sense to me as then you can use the query properties within the OnAppearing/OnNavigatedTo/etc lifecycle events.

You can follow the issue on MAUI github: Maui Shell weird navigation issue with timing of ApplyQueryAttributes and Page Lifecycle.

After some attempts, I concluded that if you want to use the default Shell structure in your project first, and then change the Shell to the Flyout structure through Shell.Current.FlyoutContent = IPlatformApplication.Current?.Services.GetService<FlyoutMenu>();, this will not work.
This will disrupt the internal operation logic of the Shell, and therefore cause ApplyQueryAttributes not to be triggered first when the pageB jumps.
I suggest that Mainpage, 、PageA, and PageB do not use the Shell structure, and set AppShell.xaml to the Flyout structure, add PageWithFlyoutMenu1ViewModel and PageWithFlyoutMenu2ViewModel in it, and then change the logic of jumping from pageB to PageWithFlyoutMenu1ViewModel in your project to jump from pageB to AppShell.
The following is the general implementation steps:
Step1: change the code in App.xaml.cs:
Public App(MainPageViewModel mainPageViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Mainpage(mainPageViewModel));
}

Step2: Change the MainPage->PageA and PageA->PageB jump logic to the following code:
await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageA(pageAViewModel));

Step3：Set the code in the appshell to Flyout structure, which means you don't need to use FlyoutMenu anymore.
<Shell ...>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Page With Flyout Menu_1">
       <Tab>
           <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{localDetail:PageWithFlyoutMenu1}" />
       </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Page With Flyout Menu_2"">
       <Tab>
           <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{localDetail:PageWithFlyoutMenu2}" />
       </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
</Shell>

Step4: change the code of Navigate method in PageBViewModel.cs:
App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();


HI Shuowen, thanks for the reply. Do you mean this code "Shell.Current.FlyoutContent = IPlatformApplication.Current?.Services.GetService();" in PageBViewModel "Navigate" RelayCommand?

Yes, I completed the code in the answer.

Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately that doesn't help me as this will display the Shell Flyout, whereas I need my own to set my own ContentView as the FlyoutContent.

I updated the answer, you can check it.

That's great much appreciated. That will require a bit of reworking my app so I'll try that soonest. Thanks for your help.

HI Shuowen, I've tried the above solution and hit a bit of an issue. I need to pass navigation parameters when navigation to "PageWithFlyoutMenu1". Do you know how I could accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

You can use messenger to pass parameters between pages. For the implementation of messenger, you can refer to Messenger and How to use WeakReferenceMessenger in MAUI?
